# What is the best method or method() for testing multiple files and see the result for each file?

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am using Intellij IDEA 2019 and junit to read a bunch of files, process them, and see if I get the right result. Here is my code:

```
@Test
public void testSolution() {
    Solver s;
    Board b;
    int counter = 0;
    final File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\EightPuzzle\\src\\ModifiedTests");

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println("processing file: " + fileEntry.getName());
        In in = new In(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
        int n = in.readInt();
        int moves = in.readInt();
        int[][] tiles = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                tiles[i][j] = in.readInt();

        b = new Board(tiles);
        s = new Solver(b);
        assertEquals(s.moves(), moves);

        counter++;
        if (counter > 10) break;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample file:

```
3
24
6   5   3 
4   1   7 
0   2   8
```

Is there any way I see which files have been processed, and what the result are? I have been trying to use the message field in the assertEquals method, but I do not know a way of accessing the result. I may need a different method?

Comment: "I do not know a way of accessing the result" - what is the "result" ? isn't it the Solver?

Comment: It is a boolean that says it is solvable, and the number of moves, which should equal the number of moves that I am reading in. Both values come from the solver. Basically I want to see if assertEquals is true or false for each file rather all of the files at once.

Comment: @Saaman Sorry, "I do not know a way of accessing the result" - this part is still not understandable. What did you mean by the "result"? Please provide sample output.

Comment: Not a problem. The result I am seeking is know if assertEquals will be true or false for each file. The way I have it right now shows the result if all files pass. I think I found a way to do it. Junit provides methods for it. Great tool. I love it. I'll post an update if / when I have the answer. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correct, maybe parameterized tests are your solution, with the files in your directory being the parameters. Please check:

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

Comment: -Thank you so much. Yes I made some progress with them, and I think I am good from here.